# Weaker form of bijection/isomorphism

Tags: functions

What is the name given to a pair of functions, $f$ and $g$, such that $f \cdot g = id$, although not neccesarily $g \cdot f = id$?

Answer (score 1):

In a category, if $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}$, we say that $f$ is a **retraction** of $g$, and that $g$ is a **section** of $f$.

Note that if $g$ is both a section and a retraction of $f$, then it is an inverse of $f$.

(We do also sometimes say that $f$ is a "left inverse" of $g$ and $g$ is a "left inverse" of $f$, but section and retraction are terms specific to morphisms/functions, while left inverse and right inverse may also refer to elements in algebraic structures such as monoids or rings)

Comment: So is it correct to call them 'inverse functions?'

Comment: @AriFordsham Not unless you have both $fg=\mathrm{id}$ *and* $gf=\mathrm{id}$. Saying "inverse functions" implies they are two-sided inverses of each other.

Comment: So, is there a term for this concept?

Comment: @AriFordsham I gave you the terms. You are commenting an answer that *gives* the terms.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we simply say that $f$ is a left inverse of $g$ or, equivalently that $g$ is a right inverse of $f$.